# How can I overwrite file contents with new content in PHP?

Tags: php, file

I tried to use fopen, but I only managed to append content to end of file. Is it possible to overwrite all contents with new content in PHP?

Comment: Sounds like you used the 'a' mode on accident. Make sure you use 'w' mode: *Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.*

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'bar');
echo file_get_contents('file.txt'); // bar
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'foo');
echo file_get_contents('file.txt'); // foo
```

Alternatively, if you're stuck with [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) you can use the `w` or `w+` modes:

> **'w'**    Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> **'w+'**    Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: `fopen` is the right tool in a lot of cases.  `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` are often misused for large strings, which hurts performance.

Comment: file_put_contents does not overwrite the existing content for me, it just appends it to the end.

Comment: @dlofrodloh For the newcomers: It shouldn't append unless you explicitly add `FILE_APPEND` flag. Maybe older PHP versions appended by mistake, I don't know. In 7.2 it overwrites as expected.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I'm using `PHP 7.0` and `fwrite()` is appending data to the file. Can you please tell how can I use `fwrite` to overwrite the file ?

Comment: Tested : `file_put_contents` replaces everything in my PHP 7.2, it only appends with `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Answer (score 7):

```
$fname = "database.php";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
$content = str_replace("192.168.1.198", "localhost", $content);

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time; this helps me with PHP & Python as well, to replace `”` when uploading the `CSV` file, furthermore, things work as expected using `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 7):

MY PREFERRED METHOD is using **fopen,fwrite and fclose** [it will cost less CPU]

```
$f=fopen('myfile.txt','w');
fwrite($f,'new content');
fclose($f);
```

> Warning for those using **file_put_contents**

It'll affect a lot in performance, for example [on the same class/situation] **file_get_contents** too: if you have a BIG FILE, it'll read the whole content in one shot and that operation could take a long waiting time

Comment: It can fail, if your script failed to create the file in question.

Comment: why would you append a recursive flag ("-r") when you are trying to delete just one file? That's a really bad *NIX practice. Also, you can achieve the very same thing by simply using PHP's unlink('myfile.txt') instead of going out of your way to exec() or shell_exec(), which can be disabled by system administrators for security purposes.