# PHP writing variables and string to text file

Tags: php

I'm trying to write to file like this:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Budapest');

    if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
        global $user;
        $user = $_POST['user'];
    } else {
        die("Nincs user beállítva!");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        global $pass;
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    } else {
        die("Nincs pass beállítva!");
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['msg'])) {
        die("Nincs üzenet!");
    } else {
        global $msg;
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    }

    if(!file_exists("logfile.txt")) {
        die("Nem létezik a logfile.txt!");
    }
    $cont = file_get_contents("logfile.txt");
    file_put_contents("logfile.txt","{$user}: {$msg}\n{$cont}"); //<-- Tried this one so many ways
?>
```

And it gives me this in the txt file:

```
<? global $user; echo $user; ?>: test
```

No matter what i change in the `file_put_contents`, it always give something similar to this.
Thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT: I made the edit that @Barmar suggested, but it is still doing the same thing:

```
<form name="send" action="chat_send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="msg" autocomplete="off" value="">
    <?php
    global $user;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . $user . '">';
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem in your code. I think the value of `$_POST['user']` is `'<? global $user; echo $user; ?>'`. I suspect the problem is with how you created the form earlier.

Comment: My guess is you wrote something like `echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php global $user; echo $user; ?>">'`. You can't use `<?php` inside a string.

Comment: Do you write permission for that file? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7551155/2191252 may help

Comment: @shridhar It looks like it's writing to the file, just not writing what he expects.

Comment: i mean to ask the file may stored at first time with the above content and it may not overwritten again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're writing to the file. The problem is most likely with how you're setting `$_POST['user']`. It looks to me like the script that created the form did something like:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php global $user; echo $user; ?>">';
```

You can't use `<?php ... ?>` in the middle of a string to execute PHP code;
That's used when you're outputing normal HTML after `?>`, to get back into PHP execution mode temporarily. So your form just contains the literal string `?php global $user; echo $user; ?>` in the hidden input value.

In a string, you use concatenation, so it should be:

```
global $user;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . $user . '">';
```

Or you can return to HTML mode first:

```
?>
<form name="send" action="chat_send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="msg" autocomplete="off" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php global $user; echo $user; ?>">
    ...
</form>
<?php
```

Comment: I edited the form as you suggested, with the echoing the hidden input, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing in a comment. Add it to the question.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: The part that displays `<form` isn't in an `echo` statement?

Comment: Yes that was the problem Thank you!