# PHP create backup /copy file + counter

Tags: php, file

I have file called test.json

I should create a backup file in any action and I just do the following action

```
copy()
```

and then it creates "test_backup_1.json"

but in the next action again I need to create "test_backup_2.json" and in the next action call: "test_backup_3.json" and so on...

How can I do that in a dynamically way . ?

Comment: You could do it with the `date()` function in PHP, or does it necessary have to be named like your example?
**Example** `copy("test.json", "test_backup_" . date("d-m-Y_H:i:s" . ".json"));` should work. Regards.

Comment: What have you tried? There are so many different ways to do this, it would great to see what went wrong with your attempts.

Comment: I did a typo on the first answer and now I can't edit it anymore, so..
**Example** `copy("test.json", "test_backup_" . date("d-m-Y_H:i:s") . ".json");` Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store or backup of the file using unique key(**UUID/GUID**) or date prefix or suffix to the file name.

```
$fileName = 'test_backup_' .  date("d-m-Y_H:i:s") . '.json'; 
copy("file.json", $fileName);
```

But as per your request, we can achieve that using **glob**

Get all the json files from your back-up folder,

```
$files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.json");
```

If you want to get exactly matched pattern files.

```
$uploadDir = 'path/to/your/upload/dir';
chdir($uploadDir);
// Will give all the files which file names starts as test_backup
$files = glob('test_backup_*');
```

The $files array contains the following from the example directory:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /path/to/directory/test_backup.json
    [1] => /path/to/directory/test_backup_1.json
    [2] => /path/to/directory/test_backup_2.json
)
```

Get the count of array then generate the index based on the count, i.e

```
$count = count($files);
$fileName = 'test_backup_' . $count  . '.json'; 
copy("file.json", $fileName);
```

For more info about glob - http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Hit  $files = glob("/path/to/directory/test_backup_*.json");    always return 0

Comment: Okay try this $files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.json"); Will retrun all .json files

Comment: @Guz, I've updated my snippet to get matched patterns, hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks, do you know how can I overwrite the existing code with new data? file put contents return false

Comment: @Guz, for file_put_content -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551132/how-can-i-overwrite-file-contents-with-new-content-in-php
If my answer helps you accept the answer.

Comment: If someone deletes some, but not all of the backups, just using the count could overwrite a previous backup